# SQL Server 2008 R2: Trigger on `TEXT` column

Tags: sql, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the table which consist of column with datatype `text`.

**Table** EmployeeMaster

```
CREATE TABLE [EmployeeMaster]
(
    EmpID int identity(1,1),
    EmpName varchar(20),
    EmpPhone int,
    EmpAddress TEXT
);
```

And I want to create audit log on this table.

**Audit Table**: EmployeeMaster_Audit

```
CREATE TABLE [EmployeeMaster_Audit]
(
    EmpID int,
    EmpName varchar(20),
    EmpPhone int,
    EmpAddress VARCHAR(MAX)
);
```

Writing trigger for INSERT.

**Trigger**:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[EmployeeMaster_Insert]
ON [dbo].[EmployeeMaster]
FOR INSERT   
AS   

 INSERT INTO [dbo].[EmployeeMaster_Audit]
([EmpID], [EmpName], [EmpPhone], [EmpAddress])
SELECT CONVERT(int,[EmpID]) as [EmpID],[EmpName],[EmpPhone],CONVERT(varchar(max),[EmpAddress]) AS [EmpAddress]  FROM INSERTED 
GO
```

**Error Details**: While creating trigger getting following error:

> Cannot use text, ntext, or image columns in the 'inserted' and 'deleted' tables.

**My Try**: `CONVERT(varchar(max),[EmpAddress])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the trigger is fired *after* the insert, you can simply query back to the `EmployeeMaster` to get the inserted data. Something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[EmployeeMaster_Insert]
ON [dbo].[EmployeeMaster]
FOR INSERT   
AS   

INSERT INTO [dbo].[EmployeeMaster_Audit] ([EmpID], [EmpName], [EmpPhone], [EmpAddress])
SELECT  EM.[EmpID]
,       EM.[EmpName]
,       EM.[EmpPhone]
,       CONVERT(varchar(max), EM.[EmpAddress]) AS [EmpAddress]  
FROM    INSERTED I
INNER JOIN  dbo.[EmployeeMaster] EM
        ON  EM.[EmpID] = I.[EmpID]
GO
```

This is assuming you cannot change the `text` datatype, see Zohar's answer.

Answer (score 2):

The correct solution to the problem would be to replace the `text` column with a `varchar(max)` column.

The `Image`, `Text`, and `nText` data types are deprecated since 2008 version introduced `varbinary(max)`, `varchar(max)` and `nvarchar(max)`.

For more information, read Microsoft official documentation page on [ntext, text, and image (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql):

> **IMPORTANT!** **ntext**, **text**, and **image** data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use **nvarchar(max)**, **varchar(max)**, and **varbinary(max)** instead.